# DynamicWeb's forum nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net, forum

I want to use the DynamicWeb's forum in my own asp.net core projects. But I couldn't find any documentation or a person who is familiar with it.

1- how can I connect it to my database
2- Is there any documentation or guide out there?

The package Link is: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dynamicweb.Forum/

Comment: Did you check their website? https://doc.dynamicweb.com/

Comment: yes. But I didn't find any related documentation

Comment: Use search - https://doc.dynamicweb.com/documentation-9/platform/advanced-settings/database

Comment: thanks. I saw that. But the description is for their CMS, not the forum package.